# Bit shifting left

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Let's say I want to bit shift `i` twice to the left and store the value in `f`.

```
f = i << 2;
```

Is that correct? How exactly do I do this in C/C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

```
f = i << 2
```

Shifts are useful in a number of bit twiddling operations.

This used to be a great way to multiply a number by four.  However, these days, optimizing compilers tend to take care of that for you.

Keep in mind that the two leftmost bits are discarded.

Comment: For Intel CPUs, the last bit shifted out of the operand is stored in the carry flag. This doesn't really add to the relevant discussion, I just wanted to say it.

Answer (score 8):

As an additional note: Even though your question is tagged `C++`, it is probably worth noting that C and C++ took slightly different paths with regard to shifting negative values. In C++ the result of doing `<<` or `>>` on a negative value is implementation-defined. In C `>>` is implementation-defined, while `<<` produces *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `i << 2`, `f = i << 2`, or `f <<= 2` are all things one might want to do to shift bits.

More shift things to keep in mind:

- you have `>>` as well.  At the bit level, `>>` works differently for signed and unsigned types.
- the priority of `<<` and `>>` is below that of `+` and `-`, which fools some people, as one might imagine them to be more like `*` and `/`.

Comment: I know this is so random, but I just wanted to let you know that this response turned on a lighbulb that helped me fix the most frustrating bug I've ever encountered while writing code. I changed all instances of signed chars to unsigned chars, and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness to help you with your bit operations you can check out this page: [uow TEXTBOOK -> bitops.html](http://www.uow.edu.au/~lukes/TEXTBOOK/notes-cpp/expressions/bitops.html)