# How can this Python code be translated to C#?

Tags: c#, python

I need to reverse engineer this code into C# and it is critical that ouput is absolutely the same. Any suggestions on the ord function and the "strHash % (1<<64)" part?

```
def easyHash(s):
    """
    MDSD used the following hash algorithm to cal a first part of partition key
    """
    strHash = 0
    multiplier = 37
    for c in s:
        strHash = strHash * multiplier + ord(c)
        #Only keep the last 64bit, since the mod base is 100
        strHash = strHash % (1<<64) 
    return strHash % 100 #Assume eventVolume is Large
```

Comment: Step 1: Learn some C#, 2: Try out your new knowledge, 3: Get stuck, 4: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: [`<<`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604368/shift-left-logical) is the left shift operator. [`%`](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html) is the modulus operator. The symbols mean the same thing in both languages.

Comment: `ord()` takes the byte value as an integer. `% (1<<64)` is masking the `strHash` integer value, rather unconventially. `& 0xffffffffffffffff` would do the same. Masking it in the loop each time is overkill however.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Considering that in Python numbers can have infinite digits, doing it in the cycle is a speedup probably. Something not necessary in C#

Comment: @xanatos: perhaps; but only if `s` is *very* large.

Comment: @xanatos: besides, the final result is then hacked down to `% 100`, so why not do *that* in the loop?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The number would be different.... The original author probably found a 64bit hash code generator for python and hacked on it a "reduce to 0...99 range"

Comment: @xanatos: the number is multiplied by 37 and the byte value added. It doesn't matter if you then mask that to 8 bytes or cap it to 100. those 7 bits are basically going to be the result of the last 2 bytes in `s` anyway, everything else will have long been multiplied too large to have any effect on those last 7 bits.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Different results: https://ideone.com/RtNsh7 and https://ideone.com/FtCM6m

Comment: @xanatos: so not `% 100`, but `& 0x7f` instead of masking it to 8 bytes (as `%100` also affects some lower bits). See https://ideone.com/wZSwPR

Comment: @MartijnPieters There must be something funny in the overflowing multiplication... https://ideone.com/34i6h5 If I use `1 << 32` instead of `1 << 64` the result is different (I had noticed it in C# using `uint` instead of `ulong`)

Comment: @xanatos: ah, of course, 37 is a prime so yes, all the characters influence the outcome. But masking to 0x7f is fine.

Comment: @xanatos: Ah well, modulo arithmetic was never my strongest. *shrug*.

Comment: @IanAuld Thanks for suggestion.  Unfortunately, I dont know any Python (do know C# pretty well) and have no way to test code against Python compiler.  This is like the only thing I ever hope to care from Python world, so no, not going to learn Python just for this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like this:

note that I'm using `ulong` instead of `long`, because I don't want that after the overflow there are negative numbers (they would mess with the calculation). I don't need to do the `strHash = strHash % (1<<64)` because with `ulong` it is implicit.

```
public static int EasyHash(string s)
{
    ulong strHash = 0;
    const int multiplier = 37;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            strHash = (strHash * multiplier) + s[i];
        }
    }

    return (int)(strHash % 100);
}
```

the `unchecked` keyword is normally not necessary, because "normally" C# is compiled in `unchecked` mode (so without checks for overflows), but code can be compiled in `checked` mode (there is an option for that). This code, as written, needs the `unchecked` mode (because it can have overflows), so I force it with the `unchecked` keyword.

Python: https://ideone.com/RtNsh7

C#: https://ideone.com/0U2Uyd

Comment: Nice explanation on the `unchecked` keyword.